# Use GHC.Generics to restrict generic function domain

Tags: haskell, ghc-generics

Say I have a typeclass:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
class Fixed a where 
  fixed :: Proxy a -> Int
```

The definition for `fixed` is quite trivial so I derive it using `GHC.Generics`:

```
class GFixed f where 
  gfixed :: Proxy (f a) -> Int

instance (GFixed f, GFixed g) => GFixed (f :*: g) where ...

instance (GFixed f, GFixed g) => GFixed (f :+: g) where ...

instance GFixed f => GFixed (M1 i c f) where ...

instance Fixed a => GFixed (K1 i a) where ...

....

default fixed :: (Generic a, GFixed (Rep a)) => Proxy a -> Int
fixed _ = fixed (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep a b))
```

I don't include an instance for `GFixed U1` because it doesn't make sense to have an instance 
of `Fixed` for void types. My understanding of `Generics` machinery is not very good - specifically, what the types of `M1` and `K1` mean. The question is as follows: can I restrict `GFixed` at the type level, so that the default definition of `fixed` doesn't work with recursive types?

For example, if I write:

```
data Void
instance Fixed Void
```

I get a type error: `No instance for (GFixed V1)`. I would like to get type error for things like `instance Fixed [Int]`.

Comment: Disabling recursive types is in general not easy. (Note that types may be mutually recursive, too, so something that doesn't look recursive at first might still turn out to be.) It would help if you could say more precisely what you want the function to do, and why exactly it should compile-time fail on recursive types.

Comment: @kosmikus The function returns the fixed size of a datatype in bytes. Not the size of the datatype in Haskell memory, the amount of memory needed to store the datatype in contiguous memory. It is clear, I think, why this doesn't work with a recursive type.

Comment: @user2407038 would you also like to get an error for `data Test1 = Test1 Test2; data Test2 = Test2 Test1; instance Fixed Test1; instance Fixed Test2` ?

Comment: @bennofs That would be ideal since they are mutually recursive. But it looks like it would be impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of work, it turns out this is fairly simple, it even works on mutually recursive types. I'm sure there are some edge cases where it fails but I haven't found any.

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    MultiParamTypeClasses
  , FunctionalDependencies
  , DataKinds
  , TypeOperators
  , TypeFamilies
  , FlexibleContexts
  , FlexibleInstances
  , UndecidableInstances
  , PolyKinds
  , ConstraintKinds
  , DeriveGeneric
  , OverlappingInstances
  #-}

module IsRecursive where 

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Proxy 

type family (:||) (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool where 
  True :|| x = True
  x :|| True = True
  a :|| b = False 

data T2 a b 

type family Elem (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) :: Bool where 
  Elem x '[] = False
  Elem x (x ': xs) = True
  Elem x (y ': xs) = Elem x xs 

class IsRecursive' (tys :: [* -> *]) (rep :: * -> *) (r :: *) | tys rep -> r where 
  isRecursive' :: Proxy tys -> Proxy rep -> Proxy r
  isRecursive' _ _ = Proxy 

-- These types have recursive `Rep`s but aren't recursive because there is no `Rep` for primitive types
instance IsRecursive' tys (K1 R Int)    (T2 False tys)
instance IsRecursive' tys (K1 R Double) (T2 False tys)
instance IsRecursive' tys (K1 R Char)   (T2 False tys)
instance IsRecursive' tys (K1 R Float)  (T2 False tys)

-- Recursive instances - unwrap one layer of `Rep` and look inside
instance IsRecursive' tys U1 (T2 False tys)
instance IsRecursive' tys (Rep c) r => IsRecursive' tys (K1 i c) r 
instance (IsRecursive' tys f (T2 r0 tys0), IsRecursive' tys g (T2 r1 tys1), r2 ~ (r0 :|| r1)) => IsRecursive' tys (f :+: g) (T2 r2 tys1)
instance (IsRecursive' tys f (T2 r0 tys0), IsRecursive' tys g (T2 r1 tys1), r2 ~ (r0 :|| r1)) => IsRecursive' tys (f :*: g) (T2 r2 tys1)
instance (IsRecursive' tys f r) => IsRecursive' tys (M1 i c f) r 

-- This is where the magic happens 
-- Datatype declaration reps are represented as `M1 D` 
-- When one is encountered, save it in the list so far and continue recursion
instance (IsRecDataDec (Elem tyrep tys) tyrep tys f r, tyrep ~ (M1 D c f)) => IsRecursive' tys (M1 D c f) r

-- Context reduction is strict, so this class makes sure we 
-- only recurse if `Elem tyrep tys == False`; otherwise every recursive type
-- would cause a stack overflow
class IsRecDataDec (b :: Bool) (c :: * -> *) (tys :: [* -> *]) (f :: * -> *) (r :: *) | b c tys f -> r 
instance IsRecDataDec True c tys f (T2 True (c ': tys))
instance IsRecursive' (c ': tys) f r => IsRecDataDec False c tys f r 

class IsRecursive t 
instance IsRecursive' '[] (Rep t) (T2 True tys) => IsRecursive t

data TBool (b :: Bool) = TBool
instance Show (TBool True) where show _ = "True"
instance Show (TBool False) where show _ = "False"

isRecursive :: IsRecursive' '[] (Rep t) (T2 r tys) => t -> TBool r
isRecursive _ = TBool

-- test cases
data K = K K deriving Generic
data A = A B deriving Generic
data B = B Q deriving Generic
data Q = Q A deriving Generic
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Generics.html) is moderately helpful for the meanings of the constructors.  `M1` specifies meta-information (such as the names of record selectors), and `K1` is a bit of a grab-bag of various things with kind `*`.  If you want to disallow all recursion, you'll need to ensure that no instance in scope matches `K1 R a`.  You'll still want some of the other `K` instances in scope, so you should change

```
instance Fixed a => GFixed (K1 i a) where
```

to

```
instance Fixed a => GFixed (K1 P a) where
```

I don't know if there are other values that can be the first parameter to `K1`, but if any arise it should be safe to add them, except for `K1 R` of course.

Comment: I thought so too, but there are obvious non-recursive types which stil have a `K1 R a`, for example `from Nothing :: D1 D1Maybe (C1 C1_0Maybe U1 :+: C1 C1_1Maybe (S1 NoSelector (K1 R a0))) x0`. Same goes for `Either` and every tuple type.

Comment: @user2407038: hmm, that's unfortunate.  It looks like `K1 R` is also used for polymorphic data.  In that case, I suspect it might be impossible to do what you want.

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.0/GHC-Generics.html is a significantly better link for documentation.

Comment: @JohnL It occurs with datatypes that are also monomorphic: `data Ty = Ty Bool == D1 D1Ty (C1 C1_0Ty (S1 NoSelector (K1 R Bool))) x0`

Comment: @kosmikus: good point.  Without extra information, I tend to link to versions from the current HP.  But it is much expanded, and contains the useful information that without a `K1` instance, the generic code may still work for types where no constructor has any fields.  Implying that a `K1` instance is necessary if any constructor has any fields.